# How do I use DOMDocument to retrieve the img path?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I have following HTML page:

```
 <div class="showtime-bg">
                <div style="float:left;">
                    <a href="javascript:getinfo(295, 1)"><img src="images/main/movies/movie.jpg" height="180" alt=""></a>

    </div>


$dom = new DOMDocument();  
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath_imgPath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$rightDivText_movie_path=$xpath_imgPath->query("//div[@class='showtime-bg']/div[0]/a/img[@src]");
```

How can I get the path using DOMDocument?

I am not able to retrieve the path.

Comment: xpath counts position from 1 - `//div[@class='showtime-bg']/div[1]/a/img[@src]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're using 0 as the base index. XPath starts the count from 1. You need to use `div[1]` instead of `div[0]`. Or just `div`. Here's how you can get the image src:

```
$xPathQuery = "//div[@class='showtime-bg']/div/a/img";
$rightDivText_movie_path=$xpath_imgPath->query($xPathQuery);   
echo $rightDivText_movie_path->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/487616)